# Separated regex and jQuery, prevent repeated characters

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I've read a lot of Stack Overflow answers about preventing repeated characters, but these are all when the regex string is in one line, like this:

```
^(?=.{4})(?!.{32})(?!.*(.)\1{4})\w[\w.-]+\w$
```

I'm using this concept for a password validation http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/01/password-strength-verification-with-jquery/ which means I want a valid class added to a list item each time one of the validation rules is passed.
There is a list of instructions above the password field, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li id="letter" class="invalid">At least <strong>3 letters</strong></li>
  <li id="number" class="invalid">At least <strong>2 numbers</strong></li>
</ul>

<input type="password" id="input-password" name="password" autocomplete="off">
```

If the users input satisfies this, then the instruction gets a tick next to it.

So, I have:

```
var pwd = $(this).val();

if ( pwd.match(/[A-z]{3,}/) ) {
        $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }
if ( pwd.match(/\d{2,}/) ) {
        $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }
```

I was hoping the {3,} would work, but in this instance, it only validates if the 3 letters are consecutive, not if they occur anywhere in the complete string. e.g. "a1aa" is invalid but "aaa" is valid.  I have read around a lot, but I'm just not understand what is needed in this situation, as I can't find other examples where the regex has been split up like this.

Any help?

**Edit**

Sorry, as nhahtdh pointed out, the title doesn't make sense in relation to the question!
I actually have an additional validation requirement which is that the password must not repeat the same letter more than 3 times.  For example, 'mississippi' would not be valid as it has more than 3 instances of the letter 's'.

Comment: What do you mean by "at least 3 letters" - does it mean that the input contains any 3 letters at any position? Another confusing thing is that - how does preventing repeated character is relevant to your question?

Comment: Sorry nhahtdh, my mistake, got myself confused with what I was asking.  I've added some more comments under the 'edit'.  In answer to your first question, the password must have at least 3 letters (a-z in upper or lowercase) in any position.

Comment: So at least 3 letters (don't care repeated), and at least 3 different letters are 2 of the requirements?

Comment: Let's hope I don't have to login to this system you're creating :)

Comment: We've had that argument and lost :( - My unenviable role is to make these intense security requirements seem simple to the user.  I put the idea in js fiddle if you're interested http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/agatg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a string with at least three letters `A-Z` `a-z` you could use

```
pwd.match( /(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){3,}/i )
```

The `i` is the case-insensitive modifier.

The regex will match zero or more characters that are not `A-Za-z`, followed by a character `A-Za-z`, three or more times.

The `?:` is optional and makes the group `()` non-capturing.

Incidentally, it is more efficient to use `test` rather than `match` if you're not actually using the match, e.g.

```
if ( /([^a-z]*[a-z]){3,}/i.test(pwd) ) {
```

*Further to comment*

To meet your additional validation requirement you could use

```
/^(?:[^a-z]*([a-z])(?!(?:.*?\1){3})){3,}[^a-z]*$/i
```

It will only match a string with at least three letters, and it uses a negative look-ahead `(?!` and back-reference `\1` to ensure the same letter (regardless of case) does not appear more than three times.

Or, if e.g. `"abcccC"` is okay because the fourth `C` is uppercase then instead you could use

```
/^(?:[^A-Za-z]*([A-Za-z])(?!(?:.*?\1){3})){3,}[^A-Za-z]*$/
```

Comment: Since you are so awesome at creating these, I would bet that he might want the 'same letter instance count' requirement to be separate from the 'min a-z' requirement.

Comment: Yes!  It's working, thanks MikeM.  Chris your bet would come in, as I do want the 'same letter instance count' to be separate from the 'min a-z' requirement.

Comment: @MikeM are you able to help me split the same letter instance count from the min a-z?  I have had a go but I must be missing something.

Comment: @davidpauljunior. For the 'no more than 3 of same letter' check you could use `if /([A-Za-z])(.*?\1){3}/.test(pwd) { // invalid`.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if ( pwd.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g).length >= 3 ) {
```

Comment: I'd rather write `>= 3`, since it is closer to the description - make it easier to detect bugs.

Comment: I was kinda thinkin the same thing when answering. No problem there. Updated

Comment: Actually, `A-z` will include garbage between `Z` and `a`. Make it `A-Za-z`, or `A-Z` with `i` flag.

Comment: Downvoted until the `A-z` is corrected. This will also throw an exception if there is no match, as `null` has no `length`.

Comment: @MikeM Good call on the null issue, didn't think of that. Did consider the A-z problem, but was using the values the OP supplied. Your answer definitely works better. The workaround for the null check is ugly, so I'm not even going to post it ;)